# Python regex alternative matches

Tags: python, regex, bash

I have a variable holding several numbers. I want to find the numbers which only contain 2 or more repeating numbers one after another. This is the bash equivalent:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

numbers="1123456789
34312323445
6564323243
8975645345"

echo $numbers | egrep '0{2,10}|1{2,10}|2{2,10}|3{2,10}|4{2,10}|5{2,10}|6{2,10}|7{2,10}|8{2,10}|9{2,10}'
```

I need a Python equivalent for the above bash code. I have tried the following but it is not working as expected:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

numbers = [1123456789, 34312323445, 6564323243, 8975645345]

pattern = re.compile('0{2,10}|1{2,10}|2{2,10}|3{2,10}|4{2,10}|5{2,10}|6{2,10}|7{2,10}|8{2,10}|9{2,10}')

for i in numbers:
    if pattern.match(str(i)):
        print(i)
```

The bash snippet is matching both `1123456789` and `34312323445` but the python snippet is only matching `11234567890`, i.e match is only occurring if the repeating numbers occurs at the begging of the number.

Comment: ``re.match`` starts at the beginning. ``re.search`` starts at an arbitrary position.

Comment: The `echo -e` trick really makes me cringe. You'll want to put literal newlines in the string in the first place instead; the shell trivially permits that. Then of course you won't need a loop to `echo` them all to `grep` in one go.

Comment: @tripleee Done. Hope that makes you feel better now :D

Comment: Thanks. Still, you could now simply `echo "$numbers" | egrep ...` without the `for` loop.

Comment: Done, removed the `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

numbers = ["1123456789", "34312323445", "6564323243", "8975645345"]

pattern = r"((\d)\2+)"

for number in numbers:
    match = re.search(pattern, number)
    if match is not None:
        print(f"{number} has repeating digits ({match.group(1)})")
```

Output:

```
1123456789 has repeating digits (11)
34312323445 has repeating digits (44)
```

The regular expression pattern works like this:

`(\d)` - This is group 2. It captures a single digit.

`\2+` - Tries to match whatever is in group 2 one or more times.

The whole thing is wrapped in another group (group 1) just for convenience.

You can also use `re.findall` to find all repeating digits in any number, not just the first match in any given number:

```
import re

numbers = ["1123455556789", "34312323445", "6564323243", "8975645345"]

pattern = r"((\d)\2+)"

for number in numbers:
    for match_groups in re.findall(pattern, number):
        print(f"{number} has repeating digits ({match_groups[0]})")
```

Output:

```
1123455556789 has repeating digits (11)
1123455556789 has repeating digits (5555)
34312323445 has repeating digits (44)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `pattern` try the below:

```py
r".*(0{2,}|1{2,}|2{2,}|3{2,}|4{2,}|5{2,}|6{2,}|7{2,}|8{2,}|9{2,}).*"
```

(assuming you don't want to cap repetitions by 10, but make it just 2, or more)

Answer (score 1):

In python you can do this:

```
>>> numbers = [1123456789, 34312323445, 6564323243, 8975645345]
>>> reg = re.compile(r'([0-9])\1')
>>> for i in numbers:
...     if reg.search(str(i)):
...             print i
...
1123456789
34312323445
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `([0-9])`: Match a digit and capture it in group #1
- `\1`: Back-reference to group #1 to make sure we have a repeat of digit

---

btw your `bash` code can also be refactored and simplified using same concept of capture group and back-reference:

```
numbers="1123456789\n34312323445\n6564323243\n8975645345"
printf '%b\n' "$numbers" | grep -E '([0-9])\1'
```

```
1123456789
34312323445
```

Comment: Not just bash code, even python regex doesn't need 2 capture groups. Just one is good enough as in my answer.